# Create image sequence with python from previously loaded images for use in Image Texture

Tags: python, texturing, keyframes

I load external user defined images (with filenames i should not change due to being referenced in other places) and store them in a collection, making sure they are packed in the blender file. I use these images as `Image Texture` for a material and i set the image dynamically based on external input from the user, snippet example:

```py
material = self.gobo_materials[obj.name].material
texture = material.node_tree.nodes.get("Image Texture")
texture.image = self.images[index].image
```

This works, but is not keyframeable. For keyframes, i have to make the `texture.image`'s `source` not to be a `FILE` but a `SEQUENCE`. Then, rather then setting `texture.image` i will  set `texture.image_user.frame_offset` based on user data and will keyframe it: `texture.image_user.keyframe_insert(data_path="frame_offset", frame=current_frame)`

How can i myself create image sequence in python, from my already loaded images?

Comment: I ended up renaming the image files and reloading them to create a sequence. For anyone else looking into this, here is the [commit](https://github.com/open-stage/blender-dmx/commit/1d087dcd3825ec5e671d589cead0b20e62d72513) in our project.